# How to avoid identation after line break in HTML

Tags: html, web

I have the following HTML body:

```
<a name="milosz"><h2>Learning</h2></a>
To believe you are magnificent.  <br>&nbsp;
And gradually to discover that you are not magnificent.<br>&nbsp;  
Enough labor for one human life.<br>&nbsp;
<br>&nbsp;
<br>
```

In the web page it appears like this:

```
To believe you are magnificent.  
 And gradually to discover that you are not magnificent.  
 Enough labor for one human life.
```

Note that the from second line onwards the sentences are indented.
Is there a way to avoid such indentation?

Comment: You need to remove the nbsp from the HTML source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start another line when using a line break with `<br>`. When followed with a space `&nbsp;` (which is the ASCII value of a space), naturally this starts the new line with a space. Try removing `&nbsp;`.

**Your case**

Code

```
First line<br>&nbsp;
Second line
```

Result

```
First line
 Second line
```

**Solution**

Code

```
First line<br>
Second line
```

Result

```
First line
Second line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<br> -- Line Break (New Line)
&nbsp; -- For Blank Space
```

You have written 
 in the end of every line this is for new line (Line Break) and for Indent you are using `&nbsp;` this is to space

so remove 
 and   to keep this in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Use  pre tag Like
open (pre) tag
formate 
you 
want 
to show
Close (pre) tag